# objectAtIndex for Nested Array iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Beginners iOS dev question here.

I have a plist in the following format:

[image]

I've converted this plist into an array in my app using:

```
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

and have verified the content using NSLog.

However the issue I have is in understanding objectAtIndex. How do i obtain Item2 in Item1 i.e. the value 6? I'm used to Javas "`array[1][2]`" style :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually still use `array[1][2]` in Objective-C (with Xcode 4). Otherwise the "Objective-C way" to do it is:

`[[array objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:2];`

But it is lots more code and for someone from most other backgrounds, not as readable either.

Comment: Array subscripting is available in Xcode 4.4 and greater or the LLVM 4.0 compiler and greater.

Answer (score 2):

It was quite tedious, but Apple have provided a simple way to do it now. Simply put, it would be:

```
array2[1][2];
```

The first number inside the square brackets sends -[array2 objectAtIndex: 1] to the top level array. The second number sends the inner array the same message with 2 as an argument.